# Why Http call using Retrofit2 (and rxjava observer) always waits for 5 secs on Wifi (Android M Nexus 6)

Tags: android, android-wifi, retrofit2

On Nexus 6 Android M (v23), calling HTTP Api using Retrofit waits for around 5 secs, before getting request hit on server.
Both the phone and the server are on the same WiFi. From browser on other workstation in same wifi gets results instantaneously (~40-60ms).
Opening same API from Android chrome on same mobile too takes 5 secs.
What can be the issue for delayed HTTP call?

**Code**:
**Retrofit2/Okhttp service Factory**

```
public class ApiGenerator {
    public static String TAG = ApiGenerator.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String API_BASE_URL = BuildConfig.API_ENDPOINT;
    public static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .create();
    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();
                Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                return response;
            }
        }).addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor());

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create());
                .....
```

**Retrofit2 Service**

```
public interface AuthService {

    @GET("/api/v1/auth")
    public void authenticate(@Query("token") String token);

    @POST("/api/v1/signup")
    Call<Object> signup();
}
```

**Service Call -**

```
Observable<Response<SignupV1Response>> observable = service.signupRx(signupReq);
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<SignupV1Response>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<SignupV1Response> response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        final int statusCode = response.code();
                        if (response.isSuccess()) {
                            // Do something
                        } else {
                            ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                            // Show error
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: ...please provide your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last found that, it has nothing to do with Okhttp and Retrofit. Its android networking issue, which has IPv6 enabled, on Andoid L (v21) and higher.
If the WiFi network does not correctly handle IPv6 (most routers including recent releases), these http client libraries takes few secs before getting response.
Refer issue - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79576

For a workaround, you can tunnel local development server to Amazon EC2 with ssh or use ngrok. Works fine with this approach.